# C# application crashes on debug

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have a multithreaded c# project. I have removed a lock, that locked unnecessarily shared objects, and tried to make those shared objects to be for single thread. 
The thing is now the process is  crashing, with no error whats so ever - not in the event viewer or when I run in debug. 
Can anyone suggest a way for me to diagnose the error? Because the fact that visual studio just lets the process stop with nothing for me to work with makes me stuck. My last resort is WinDbg, and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Make sure you enable Visual Studio to break on all exceptions. Hit ctrl+alt+e to bring up the exceptions window.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to hook into unhandled app domain exceptions - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

and also check out unhandled thread exceptions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

(code from example in appdomain link)

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Example 
{
   [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
   public static void Main()
   {
      AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
      currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

      try {
         throw new Exception("1");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : {0} \n", e.Message);
      }

      throw new Exception("2");
   }

   static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
   {
      Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
      Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
      Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Catch clause caught : 1 
//        
//       MyHandler caught : 2 
//       Runtime terminating: True 
//        
//       Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: 2 
//          at Example.Main()
```

Comment: weird...apart from windbg the only other option I can think of is making sure you break on all errors as MrWombat says...

Answer (score 0):

It's also a good idea to check the Exceptions that cause a Debugger-break in Visual studio.

You can find this unter `Debug->Exceptions...` or with `Crtl+D, E`

Maybe visual studio just skips the exception that is causing your crash